# Making a request to a specific server with "speedtest-cli" for python

Tags: python-3.x, server, speed-test

I wrote a code that does a speed test every 3 hours using python. `get_best_server()` can make requests to servers far away from me. When I do it on the website, it really finds the closest city-based. I have the server id closest to me, how can I request it?

```
    import speedtest

    test = speedtest.Speedtest(secure=1)
    test.get_servers()
    best = test.get_best_server()
    
    print(f"Found:{best['host']} located in  {best['country']}")

    download_result = test.download()
    upload_result = test.upload()
    ping_result = test.results.ping


    print(f"Download Speed: {download_result / 1024 / 1024:.2f} Mbit/s")
    print(f"Upload Speed: {upload_result / 1024 / 1024:.2f} Mbit/s")
    print(f"Ping: {ping_result}s")
```

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but I face the same issue; here's how I solved it ([official example](https://github.com/sivel/speedtest-cli/wiki#python-api)) :

```
import speedtest


test = speedtest.Speedtest(secure=True)

#define the list of servers that you want to run against
test.get_servers(servers=["5738","10241"])


best = test.get_best_server()
print(f"Found:{best['host']} located in  {best['country']}")


download_result = test.download()
print(f"Download Speed: {download_result / 1024 / 1024:.2f} Mbit/s")


upload_result = test.upload()
print(f"Upload Speed: {upload_result / 1024 / 1024:.2f} Mbit/s")


ping_result = test.results.ping
print(f"Ping: {ping_result}s")
```

However, since you add `secure=True` if your `server-list` contains servers without HTTPS, it gives you an errors. Because of that, either remove `secure=True` or only include servers with HTTPS.